# Why is data is not added to the cell?

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update

Can you tell me why the data is not being added to the specified cell?
I'm trying to collect all the numbers in a list and put them in a cell. The script fulfills, clears a cell, but the data in a cell does not appear.
It is necessary to put the list in exactly one cell, because this is how freebx works

[image]

```
#/usr/bin/python3

import mysql.connector

try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                     database='asterisk',
                                     user='freepbxuser',
                                     password='',
                                     autocommit=True)
    sql_select_Query = "SELECT CONCAT(cell) FROM userman_users"
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
    dirty_text = [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
    for item in dirty_text.copy():
        if item is None:
           dirty_text.remove(item)
    SYMBOLS = '{}()[].,:;+-*/&|<>=~'
    clear_text = []
    for element in dirty_text:
        temp = ""
        for ch in element:
            if ch not in SYMBOLS:
                temp += ch
        clear_text.append(temp)
    values = [list([item]) for item in clear_text]
    cursor.executemany ("""
    UPDATE pinsets
    SET passwords=%s
    WHERE pinsets_id=1
    """, (values))
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    print("Error", e)
finally:
    if connection.is_connected():
        connection.close()
        cursor.close()
```

Comment: Why do you write `CONCAT(cell)`? `CONCAT` is for concatenating multiple strings, it doesn't do anything useful with just one argument.

Comment: [Don't remove from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it). Use `dirty_list = [item for item in dirty_list if item is not None]`

Comment: You don't need to call `list()` in `list([item])`. `[item]` is already a list.

Comment: Are you trying to put a comma-separated list of values in the `passwords` cell?

Comment: That's generally not a good idea, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad. But if it's what you really want, you need to use `value = ','.join(values)` and then just execute one `UPDATE` to add that, not `executemany()`.

Comment: `executemany()` is just a shortcut for looping over the list and executing a separate query for each element. So you'll repeatedly update the same row with a different value from the list, and end up with just the last value.

Comment: Right.  There is NO POINT in using `executemany` when you have `pinsets_id=1`.  That would repeatedly update that one row over and over and over.

Comment: I use concat to get a clean list of phone numbers from another table.
I'm trying to put in a list of passwords where each number is on a separate line.
Thank you very much, I will try your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what I THINK you were trying to do.  This fetches all of the non-NULL values from the "cell" column from "userman_users", removes any special characters from them, and stores them as a comma-separated list in the one row in "pinsets":

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                 database='asterisk',
                                 user='freepbxuser',
                                 password='',
                                 autocommit=True)
sql_select_Query = "SELECT cell FROM userman_users;"
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
dirty_text = [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall() if i[0]]

SYMBOLS = '{}()[].,:;+-*/&|<>=~'
clear_text = []
for element in dirty_text:
    clear_text.append( ''.join(ch for ch in element if ch not in SYMBOLS) )

cursor.execute ("""
    UPDATE pinsets
    SET passwords=%s
    WHERE pinsets_id=1;
""", (','.join(clear_text),)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try your version.
As a result, I need to get a list of numbers, one in each line, without commas in the cell.
Thank you very much again

Comment: I changed (','.join(clear_text),) to ('\n'.join(clear_text),) And everything worked as expected. Thanks a lot for your time and help.